# ios voiceover for UITableView sections

Tags: ios, uitableview, accessibility, voiceover

Is there some way that I can avoid the section titles of the UITableView from saying "heading" in the voiceover mode after the text on the section is read? I am providing custom views in viewForHeaderInSection: . I have tried setting isAccessibilityElement to NO and accessibilityTraits to UIAccessibilityTraitNone for the custom view that I return in viewForHeaderInSection. But I cannot suppress the callout "heading" in voiceover mode. For e.g. if I set the label in the section as "Dates", it will be read out as Dates "pause" heading.

The reason I need to do this is that some of the sections are just custom messages with 0 rows, they are not really headings of any kind. I do not want to have them as rows within a section.

Comment: If some of the headings aren't headings don't declare them as headings. Why shouldn't they be within a section. You can have sections without headings.

Comment: @dasdom - Could you please elaborate  - "don't declare them as headings"? The UIView that I return in viewForSection just has one UILabel subview with text "Dates". But in voiceover it is read as "Dates heading". Is there some attribute I need to set.

Comment: No, I mean make the headings which aren't actually headings rows and put them in a sections without a heading.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but I do not have the choice of having them as rows, it will need too much change. I am just looking for a way to suppress the heading callout

Answer (score 0):

Answering my question to document the solution that I went with. Used a custom view that implements UIAccessibilityContainer and returned that in viewForHeaderInSection. Implemented the three methods in the protocol to only mark the label in the view as an accessibility element. This is the only way I could get the section to not append "heading" at the end of the label voiceover readout.

Comment: Can you share the UIAccessibilityContainer code that you used?

Comment: @Kedar: could you provide the code that solved this problem, please ? Unfortunately, I think your solution works only if you haven't other section headers to be build when scrolling is necessary. If it's not the case, I'd like to know why.  ;o)

Answer (score 0):

You can implement accessibilityElementDidBecomeFocused method in your custom view,when this view did become focused and post UIAccessibilityLayoutChangedNotification to VoiceOver and focus to itself, and then return the traits UIAccessibilityTraitNone

```
- (void)accessibilityElementDidBecomeFocused {
       UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityLayoutChangedNotification,   self);
}

- (UIAccessibilityTraits)accessibilityTraits {
    return UIAccessibilityTraitNone;
}
```